# Break a huge database into columns

Tags: r

I started to manage a huge (few ten thousands record) data, and I need to break it into columns. the database is repeating, like:

```
a 2,1
b 3,4
c 3,2
d 2,5
a 3,5
b 4,7
c 8,1
d 5,1
a ...
```

and so on. One circle is 1024 records long, one database is few ten thousand. Do you have any idea how can I arrange it into table, like:

```
a 2,1 3,5 ...
b 3,4 4,7
c 3,2 8,1
d 2,5 5,1
```

It would be good, if I can add a number to every column, like:

```
 0,2 0,4 0,6 0,8...
a 2,1 3,5 ...
b 3,4 4,7
c 3,2 8,1
d 2,5 5,1
```

But this is not vital.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dcast` from `library(data.table)`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), create a sequence column ('N') grouped by 'v1', and use then reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
dcast(setDT(df1)[, N:= paste0('val', 1:.N), by = v1], v1~N, value.var='v2')
#    v1 val1 val2
#1:  a  2,1  3,5
#2:  b  3,4  4,7
#3:  c  3,2  8,1
#4:  d  2,5  5,1
```

In the devel version i.e. `v1.9.7`, we can create the sequence column using `rowid`

```
dcast(setDT(df1), v1~rowid(v1, prefix='val'), value.var='v2')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"), 
v2 = c("2,1", "3,4", "3,2", "2,5", "3,5", "4,7", "8,1", "5,1"
)), .Names = c("v1", "v2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, same idea as @akrun, using `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(v1) %>% 
  mutate(v0 = paste0('val', 1:n())) %>% 
  spread(v0, v2)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#
#     v1  val1  val2
#  (chr) (chr) (chr)
#1     a   2,1   3,5
#2     b   3,4   4,7
#3     c   3,2   8,1
#4     d   2,5   5,1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to put this data in long form:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

df1 %>%
  mutate(record = 1:n(),
         v2 = v2 %>% stri_split_fixed(",") ) %>%
  unnest(v2) %>%
  group_by(record) %>%
  mutate(order = 1:n())
```

Both the record and the order columns are optional.